# struct incomplete type error with gcc-3.3.4

Tags: c, linux, gcc, struct

I have tried a simple example as follows:

```
#include <linux/fs.h>

struct fakes {
 struct address_space mapping;
};

int main(){ return 0;}
```

And I compiled the code with `gcc-3.3.4` this way: `gcc -I/usr/src/kernel-headers-2.4.26-1/include simple.c`. But the compiler tells me the error that `field 'mapping' has incomplete type`. Besides, I have already looked at the file `/usr/src/kernel-headers-2.4.26-1/include/linux/fs.h` and the `struct address_space` has no `typedef` declaration.

Comment: How sure are you that it's using the header in that location?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks for your reply.  Could you please go into more details? I have specified the searching path with `gcc -I/usr/src/kernel-headers-2.4.26-1/include simple.c`.

Comment: What do you think `<linux/fs.h>` will match?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It seems that I am wrong. For example, if I put a file named `my.h` under `/usr/src/kernel-headers-2.4.26-1/include/linux` and add `#include <linux/my.h>`. Then compile with `-I/usr/src/kernel-headers-2.4.26-1/include`, it reports the error that `linux/my.h no such file or directory`. So where is `#include <linux/fs.h>` located when I compile with  `-I/usr/src/kernel-headers-2.4.26-1/include`

Comment: Under `/usr/include`, where the files for the current (or near-current) running kernel are located.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If so, what's the use of `-I/usr/src/kernel-headers-2.4.26-1/include`

Comment: It's for headers not found in system locations, unless those locations are disabled.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks for your reply. Yes, you're right. But my problem still remains there. I looked at the file `/usr/include/linux/fs.h` and I found `struct address_space` there. I still do not understand what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Perhaps try adding the `-H` switch to gcc to confirm what headers are being checked.  For what it's worth, my `/usr/include/linux/fs.h` doesn't have `struct address_space`.  (And this error is consistent with what you'd get if no `struct address_space` definition was found.)